# Detecting multiple platforms- c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, game-development

I'm making a platformer for my A Level programming project where the player automatically jumps on a platform upon touching it. However, I'm having trouble with the collision detection because it only bounces on one platform and falls right through the rest. they all have the same tags so i know that's not the issue.

the way that it's coded is that it will detect collision with any rectangle with the tag 'platform' however it only detects collision with 1 rectangle

Code sample below:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer GameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private bool LeftKeyPressed, RightKeyPressed, gravity; 
        double score;
        //this value will increase to be 5x the highest Y value so the score increases the higher Meke gets
        private float SpeedX, SpeedY, FrictionX = 0.88f, Speed = 1, FrictionY = 0.80f;
        //SpeedX controls horizontal movement, SpeedY controls vertical movement

        private void Collide(string Dir)
        {
            foreach (var x in GameScreen.Children.OfType<Rectangle>())
            {
                if (x.Tag != null)
                {

                    var platformID = (string)x.Tag;
                    if (platformID == "platform")
                    {


                        x.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                        Rect MeekHB = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(Meek), Canvas.GetTop(Meek), Meek.Width, Meek.Height);
                        Rect PlatformHB = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(x), Canvas.GetTop(x), x.Width, x.Height);
                        int Jumpcount = 1;
                        if (MeekHB.IntersectsWith(PlatformHB))
                        {

                            if (Dir == "y")
                            {
                                while (Jumpcount != 700)
                                {
                                    gravity = false;
                                    Jumpcount = Jumpcount + 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            gravity = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void KeyboardUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //this is what detects when the 'A' key is being pressed
            if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                LeftKeyPressed = false;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.D)
            {
                RightKeyPressed = false;
            }
        }

        private void KeyboardDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                LeftKeyPressed = true;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.D)
            {
                RightKeyPressed = true;
            }
        }




        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GameScreen.Focus();

            GameTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16);
            GameTimer.Tick += GameTick;
            GameTimer.Start();
        }
        private void GameTick(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtScore.Content = "Score: " + score;

            if (LeftKeyPressed)
            {
                SpeedX -= Speed;
            }

            if (RightKeyPressed)
            {
                SpeedX += Speed;
            }

            if (gravity == true)
            {
               SpeedY += Speed;
            }

            else if (gravity == false)
            {
                SpeedY -= Speed+50;
            }


            SpeedX = SpeedX * FrictionX;
            SpeedY = SpeedY * FrictionY;


            Canvas.SetLeft(Meek, Canvas.GetLeft(Meek) + SpeedX);
            Collide("x");
            Canvas.SetTop(Meek, Canvas.GetTop(Meek) + SpeedY);
            Collide("y");



            double maxY = 0;
            if (Canvas.GetBottom(Meek) > maxY)
            {
                maxY = Canvas.GetBottom(Meek);
            }

            score = maxY;
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need smooth animation? It's possible to consider px by ox positions for collision but that's fiddly. Eg where are the edges of your little man compared to his given point. I would instead maybe think of the playing area in terms of a grid of larger squares. They can then be represented by a 2d array and indexed by integer X,Y. When two objects X,y co ordinates are the same then you have a collision. Objects like floors can fill a square so you can't move into that square.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your `gravity = true` logic. You make check for intersections in loop for all platforms, so even if first platform in loop sets gravity to false, next platform in loop will set gravity to true again and logic won't work. As far as I understand, your logic works only to detect last platform in GameScreen.Children.OfType(). Maybe try to `break;` you loop after you found an intersection.

And for future - add some logs to your app to be able to debug such issues. Most likely your game library provide some ways to print debug messages - add them to your code so you can see, what's going on.

And also your `while (Jumpcount != 700)` loop looks useless

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, the cod is now running as intended